# vue-cli build fails with compile errors

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

My Vue 2.6.11 app is failing to build with 4 TypeScript-related errors that I am not sure how to remedy.

package.json
**vue: 2.6.11
typescript: 2.9.10**

**Here is what the console looks like:
**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhTtF.png)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you check if somewhere you used `import { types } from "vue"`?

Comment: I did not use this code.

Comment: typescript 2.9 is very old.  try upgrading to something more recent (>=4.0)

Comment: Typescript upgrade 4.4.4 version 
Here is what the console looks like https://ibb.co/C2TMynn